# How to enable https in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, https, ssl-certificate

1. I have applied a free certificate for my website and successfully installed the certificate in the certificate store. And the CN is the same as my domain(issued to mydomain).
2. I also set up the site bindings and added an https binding using the free certificate.
3. The port 443 is opened for both inbound and outbound.
4. Windows Network Troubleshooting detected the **resource(my domain) is online but isn't responding to connection attempt**.

But I still get **ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** error from the browser.

Did I miss any steps? How could I enable the https in IIS?

***UPDATE 11/14/2018***

I have run bindings diagnostics and SSL diagnostics using `JexusManager` suggested by @Lex Li, and got more information as below:

**Binding Diagnostics:**

> BINDING: https *:443:whatever.com
>
> This site can take external traffic if,
>
> - TCP port 443 must be opened on Windows Firewall (or any other equivalent products).
> - Requests from web browsers must be routed to following end points on this machine,
>
>   - [::1]:443.
>   - My.private.IP.address:443.
>
> This site can take local traffic at 127.0.0.1:443.
>
> This site can take local traffic at [::1]:443.
>
> - Web browsers should use URL https://whatever.com:443. Requests must have Host header of "whatever.com".
>     Start DNS query for whatever.com.
>     DNS Query returns 1 result(s).
>
>   - 127.0.0.1
>
> **Binding Diagnostics does not verify certificates and other SSL/TLS related settings.**
>
> **Please run SSL Diagnostics at server level to analyze SSL/TLS configuration.**

**And then I ran SSL diagnostics as below:**

> BINDING: https *:443:whatever.com
>
> SSLCertHash: 2962cd5b2b450403bce520169c268de1f17a6216
>
> SSL Flags: None
>
> Testing EndPoint: 127.0.0.1
>
> CertName: whatever.com
>
> Version: 3
>
> You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
>
> Signature Algorithm: sha256RSA
>
> Key Exchange Algorithm: RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx Key Size: 2048
>
> Subject: CN=whatever.com
>
> Issuer: CN=TrustAsia TLS RSA CA, OU=Domain Validated SSL, O="TrustAsia
>
> Technologies, Inc.", C=CN
>
> Validity: From 11/11/2018 4:00:00 PM To 11/12/2019 4:00:00 AM
>
> Serial Number: 0B365B8ABC8118CD7F818FD5B7BB485C
>
> DS Mapper Usage: Disabled
>
> Archived: False
>
> Subject Alternative Name: DNS Name=whatever.com DNS Name=www.whatever.com
>
> Key Usage: KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature
>
> Enhanced Key Usage: Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1),Client
>
> Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
>
> Basic Constraints: Subject Type=End Entity, Path Length Constraint=None
>
> **Certificate verified.**

And, I also have run an SLL Checker and it returns:

> whatever.com resolves to My.Public.IP.Address
>
> Server Type: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>
> No SSL certificates were found on whatever.com. Make sure that the name resolves to the correct server and that the SSL port (default is 443) is open on your server's firewall.

The certificate passed the SSL Diagnostics but it has some problem. I didn't get it. How could I enable https protocol for my site? Many thanks!

Comment: Without more information, there are too many possibilities to cover in this sort of forum. I suggest checking the [W3C logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/w3c-logging) to ensure the traffic is being received and is coming in on the right port, and to check for strange patterns such as a redirect loop. Also, try accessing the site from a browser running on the server itself, bearing in mind that the browser might try a [CRL check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list) that could be blocked by the server infrastructure.

Comment: Run a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html and edit your question to include it. You might need to run another report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @John Wu I could only access to the site through https protocol from a browser on the server by adding `172.0.0.1   whatever.com` in the host file. And I pretty much sure that the certificate does not expire. I will find a way out to check the W3C logs. Thanks!

Comment: If you can access the web site via https from the server but from nowhere else, the likely culprit is a firewall or other network node blocking inbound on port 443. This could happen for example in a data center with SSL offloading and termination at the perimeter, which would preclude any need for 443 within. There's probably 100 other possibilities. Anyway, this doesn't sound like a programming problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

As @John Wu said, this is not a programming problem but a network gateway problem.

First, the certificate has no problem and so does the server/firewall setting.

The problem occurred in the network gateway of the cloud service provider that blocked the 443 port inbound and outbound. In my case, I am using AliCloud server and it blocked every request which went through 443 port from the public network. And this is why I could only get access to the SSL website through the browser on the server.

The solution is very simple. The only thing needs to do is to inform the cloud service provider to open the 443 port. In my case, I just added the 443/443 port authorization in the control panel of the cloud servers and then everything fixed.